# What if one process in a MPI program proceeds more slowly than others?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

Say you have a MPI program where one process has more work to do than other processes. For example, the root process performs an extra function that other processes don't.

Will the program automagically wait for the root process to finish its extra function, before proceeding with other processes? Or will the root process start lagging behind other processes?

Comment: There's no magic. If you want synchronization, *you* have to provide it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Very well. If every process has the same amount of work, are all processes guaranteed to be synchronized (I doubt it)?

Comment: All processes are independent unless you use some synchronization mechanism like `MPI_Barrier`.

Comment: @Drew No they are not. One process may be scheduled to run on the CPU constantly (thus completing it's work fast) and some other process may be scheduled rarely (completing it's work slower). The amount of work doesn't matter. You are not, in general, guaranteed any fairness in process scheduling.

Comment: @Evg so you could place a `MPI_Barrier` every line to guarantee total synchronization? Or just smartly place it to get synchronization at necessary parts?

Comment: @Drew, you use synchronization when you need it.

Comment: If you think you need total synchronization, then there is very likely something wrong with your algorithm. MPI synchronization can be explicit (e.g. Barrier) or implicit (a fast process is stuck in a receive, and wait for the slow process to send. Also, some collectives such as allreduce also performs implicit synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't. It may works in some arbitrary executions, but if you don't provide any kind of synchronization mechanism you can't ensure this.

You should look to `MPI_Barrier()`. Also you can use `MPI_Ssend()` and `MPI_Recv()` to perform this synchronization.